# order query in sqlite with date format with cast as int

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I would like to change my query to apply `ASC` order. This is my query that changes date format and sorts correctly in `DESC` mode.

```
   public Cursor get(String Filter1, String Order1)
{
String Sort="data"; 
if (Order1=="data")
{
    Sort="substr(data, 7, 4), substr(data, 4, 2), substr(data, 1, 2)";
}
else {Sort="players";}

try

{
   String sql3 ="SELECT rowid _id, * FROM players"
        + " WHERE players like ('"+ Filter1 +"')"
        //+ " ORDER BY "+ Sort +"";
        + " ORDER BY "+ Sort +"";

    Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql3, null);
     if (mCur!=null)
     {
        mCur.moveToNext();
     }
     return mCur;
 }
 catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
 {
     Log.e(TAG, "getGiocatoriTutti >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
     throw mSQLException;
}
```

Adding `ASC` or `DESC` at the end doesn't works.

```
ORDER BY "+ Sort +" ASC";
```

Change to:

```
   Sort="cast (substr(date,7,4) as int) ASC"
```

sorts correctly only by year.

I try

```
Sort="cast (substr(date,7,4), substr(date 4,2), substr(date 1,2) as int) ASC"
```

but isn't the right sintax.

Comment: What's wrong in using `... ORDER BY Date ASC`? Why do you want to cast it to INTEGER? TimeStrings are already sortable as they are, if you use the correct format (i.e.: `YYYY-MM-DD`)

Comment: In database my date is stored as dd/mm/yyyy format. And I"ve to change it  in yyyymmdd format with substr.... but add ASC or DESC doesnt take effect.

Comment: `In database my date is stored as dd/mm/yyyy format` Well, you did a **bad mistake**, then. See here: https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Is a preexisting database and I only have to retrieve data.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to update all the dates to the correct format.

Comment: But finally I've also to show date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: And then use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for that purpose... **in your app** - not inside the db! The data in the db must be in the correct format. Then in your app you are free to present it as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, here my solution:

```
Sort="substr(data,7,4)||substr(data,4,2)||substr(data,1,2) DESC";
```

Comment: You're the one who fixes a hole in a tire with some chewing gum, huh?!

Comment: I mean, using anti-patterns won't make your apps smarter.